# How can I get my search bar header to work in the same section as my cells?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, uisearchbar

I have a header containing a search bar which searches through cells. But the only way I could get the search bar to work was to put it as a section head in a different section from the cells it looks through. Is it possible to put a search bar and its cells in the same section. Thank you for all of your help in advance.

Code so far below:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate, UISearchBarDelegate {

    lazy var collectionView : UICollectionView = {
        let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
        layout.sectionHeadersPinToVisibleBounds = true
        let cv = UICollectionView(frame: .zero, collectionViewLayout: layout)
        cv.backgroundColor = .white
        cv.delegate = self
        cv.dataSource = self
        return cv
    }()

    var genericTagsArray:[String] = ["tag1","tag2","tag3","tag4","tag5","tag6","tag7","tag8","tag9","tag10","tag11","tag12","A","B","C","D","E","F","G","Ab","Abc","za","tag1","tag2","tag3","tag4","tag5","tag6","tag7","tag8","tag9","tag10","tag11","tag12","A","B","C","D","E","F","G","Ab","Abc","za"]

    var currentTagsArray:[String] = [String]() {
        didSet {
            collectionView.reloadSections(IndexSet.init(integer: 1))
        }
    }


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.view.addSubview(collectionView)
        collectionView.register(Cell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "cell")
        collectionView.register(Header.self, forSupplementaryViewOfKind: UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader, withReuseIdentifier: "header")
        collectionView.anchor(top: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor, leading: self.view.leadingAnchor, bottom: self.view.bottomAnchor, trailing: self.view.trailingAnchor, padding: .init(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0))
        collectionView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 0)


    }


    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        if section == 0 { return 0 }
        return currentTagsArray.count
    }

    func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
        return 2
    }
    var header:Header = Header()
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind kind: String, at indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionReusableView {
        header = collectionView.dequeueReusableSupplementaryView(ofKind: UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader, withReuseIdentifier: "header", for: indexPath) as! Header
        header.searchBar.delegate = self
        return header
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, referenceSizeForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGSize {
        if section == 0 {
            return CGSize(width: self.view.frame.width, height: 50)
        }
        return CGSize()
    }


    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! Cell
        cell.label.text = currentTagsArray[indexPath.item]
        return cell
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {

        return CGSize(width: self.view.frame.size.width, height: 50)

    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumInteritemSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return 5
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumLineSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return 5
    }

    func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {
        self.currentTagsArray = self.genericTagsArray.filter { (text) -> Bool in
            return text.contains(searchText.lowercased())
        }
    }


}

class Cell : UICollectionViewCell {

    let label = UILabel()

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        setupViews()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    func setupViews() {
        self.backgroundColor = .gray
        self.addSubview(label)
        label.anchor(top: self.topAnchor, leading: self.leadingAnchor, bottom: self.bottomAnchor, trailing: self.trailingAnchor)
    }

}

class Header : UICollectionViewCell {

    let searchBar = UISearchBar()

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        setupViews()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    func setupViews() {
        self.backgroundColor = .gray
        self.addSubview(searchBar)
        searchBar.anchor(top: self.topAnchor, leading: self.leadingAnchor, bottom: self.bottomAnchor, trailing: self.trailingAnchor)
    }

}

extension UIView {
    func anchor(top: NSLayoutYAxisAnchor?, leading: NSLayoutXAxisAnchor?, bottom: NSLayoutYAxisAnchor?, trailing: NSLayoutXAxisAnchor?, padding: UIEdgeInsets = .zero, size: CGSize = .zero) {
        translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        if let top = top {
            topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: top, constant: padding.top).isActive = true
        }

        if let leading = leading {
            leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leading, constant: padding.left).isActive = true
        }

        if let bottom = bottom {
            bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottom, constant: -padding.bottom).isActive = true
        }

        if let trailing = trailing {
            trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: trailing, constant: -padding.right).isActive = true
        }

        if size.width != 0 {
            widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: size.width).isActive = true
        }

        if size.height != 0 {
            heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: size.height).isActive = true
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not good practice to put search inside one of the cells. That being said, you can try something like this, even tho it feels like a hack:

```
var currentTagsArray:[String] = [String]() {
    didSet {
        collectionView.reloadData()
    }
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.view.addSubview(collectionView)
    collectionView.register(Cell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "cell")
    collectionView.register(Header.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "\(Header.self)")
    collectionView.anchor(top: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor, leading: self.view.leadingAnchor, bottom: self.view.bottomAnchor, trailing: self.view.trailingAnchor, padding: .init(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0))
    collectionView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 0)
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return currentTagsArray.count + 1
}

func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, referenceSizeForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGSize {

    return CGSize(width: self.view.frame.width, height: 50)
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    if indexPath.section == 0 && indexPath.item == 0 {

        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "\(Header.self)", for: indexPath) as! Header
        cell.searchBar.delegate = self
        searchCell = cell

        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            if self.currentTagsArray.count != 0 {
                self.searchCell?.searchBar.becomeFirstResponder()
            }
        }

        return cell
    }

    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! Cell
    cell.label.text = currentTagsArray[indexPath.item - 1]
    return cell
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {

    return CGSize(width: self.view.frame.size.width, height: 50)
}
```

And don't forget to remove your logic for header.

Going to stress again about this, it's no good practice, so use on your own risk.

Comment: Thank you so much for your response so far it seems to be the only solution that behaves well. How much of hack could it really be if it works? The only reservation I have is I would like to enable something similar to sticky headers. Would that be possible if the search bar were in a cell?

Comment: yea, same rules going to apply to sticky headers